# How to implement address search with autosuggestions like google maps?

Tags: android, kotlin, autocomplete, here-api, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to implement instant search by address like in Google or HERE Maps using HERE library.
I need to show suggestions when user types several words sequentially even if user miss commas, dots, etc. Though request with missing punctuation works I can't figure out how could I display suggestions returned by request.

I tried to use `AutoCompleteTextView`, but it works only for first word, when I enter one more word it stops working.

Also I tried to use [floatingsearchview (arimorty) library](https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview), but it seems not to be working with androidx. I called `swapSuggestions(suggestions)` on focus, but it works only once in a fragment, though in an activity it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, as suggested, by applying custom adapter. But this adapter is analogy of version from Google for Google Place API. Thanks for [this guide](https://www.zoftino.com/google-places-auto-complete-android)

#### Extension function

First of all you need to add this extension function for `TextAutoSuggestionRequest` class to convert callbacks into coroutine for using it like syncronized code

```
suspend fun TextAutoSuggestionRequest.await(): MutableList<AutoSuggest> {
    return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
        execute { suggestions, errorCode ->
            if (errorCode == ErrorCode.NONE) {
                continuation.resume(suggestions)
            } else {
                continuation.resumeWithException(Exception("Error code: $errorCode"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### locationServicesAddress()

Then add this converter. I converted geo coordinates to text via standart location services instead of Here GeoCoder because I don't like how it returns address.

```
fun locationServiceAddress(context: Context, coordinate: GeoCoordinate): String {
    val googleGeoCoder = Geocoder(context)
    val addresses = googleGeoCoder.getFromLocation(coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude, 1)
    return addresses[0].getAddressLine(0)
}
```

Though you could use Here GeoCoder with another extension function for simplicity sake:

```
suspend fun ReverseGeocodeRequest.await(): String {
    return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
        execute { location, errorCode ->
            if (errorCode == ErrorCode.NONE) {
                continuation.resume(location.address.text)
            } else {
                continuation.resumeWithException(Exception("Error code: $errorCode"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### SuggestionsAdapter.kt

Add this adapter

Note that if you try to return `object : Filter() {}` in `getFilter()` it won't work properly because requests will stack in that object instead of interrupting (recreating the class)

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Filter
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import com.here.android.mpa.common.GeoCoordinate
import com.here.android.mpa.search.AutoSuggestPlace
import com.here.android.mpa.search.TextAutoSuggestionRequest
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import timber.log.Timber

data class AddressItem(val coordinate: GeoCoordinate, val addressText: String)


class SuggestionsAdapter(context: Context, private val resourceId: Int, private val coordinate: GeoCoordinate) : ArrayAdapter<AddressItem>(context, resourceId, ArrayList<AddressItem>()) {
    companion object {
        private val _isFetching = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
        val isFetching: LiveData<Boolean>
            get() = _isFetching
    }

    private var suggestions = ArrayList<AddressItem>()
    private val customFilter = CustomFilter()

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        var view = convertView
        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context!!).inflate(resourceId, parent, false)
        }
        val item = getItem(position)
        if (item != null) {
            val addressText = view!!.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_address_text)
            addressText.text = item.addressText
        }

        return view!!
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): AddressItem? {
        return try {
            suggestions[position]
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Timber.d("Item is NULL")
            null
        }
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return suggestions.size
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int) = position.toLong()

    override fun getFilter(): Filter = customFilter


    inner class CustomFilter : Filter() {
        override fun convertResultToString(resultValue: Any?): CharSequence {
            if (resultValue != null) {
                val address = resultValue as AddressItem
                return address.addressText
            }
            return "" // if item is null
        }

        override fun performFiltering(prefix: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
            val results = FilterResults()
            val suggestions = ArrayList<AddressItem>()

            if (prefix == null || prefix.isEmpty()) {
                results.values = ArrayList<AddressItem>()
                results.count = 0
            } else {

                val request = TextAutoSuggestionRequest(prefix.toString()).setSearchCenter(coordinate)

                Timber.d("Start perform filtering")

                runBlocking {
                    Timber.d("Blocking coroutine scope started")
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        isFetching.value = true
                    }

                    // Get places on IO thread
                    val requestResult = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        Timber.d("Getting places on IO thread")
                        request.await()
                    }

                    var i = 0
                    for (place in requestResult) {
                        i++
                        // If there are more than 10 suggestions break the loop because the more addresses found the more time need to process them to a string
                        if (i == 10) {
                            break
                        }
                        if (place is AutoSuggestPlace) {
                            val item = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                                AddressItem(place.position, locationServiceAddress(context, place.position))
                            }
                            suggestions.add(item)
                        }
                    }

                    Timber.d("Blocking coroutine scope finished")
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        isFetching.value = false
                    }

                    results.apply {
                        values = suggestions
                        count = suggestions.size
                    }
                    Timber.d("Filtered results: ${suggestions}")
                }
            }
            return results

        }


        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
            try {
                if (results?.count!! > 0 && results?.values != null) {
                    suggestions = results.values as ArrayList<AddressItem>
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                } else {
                    suggestions = ArrayList()
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated()
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Timber.d("Caught exception: ${e.message}")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and set it in Here `SupporMapFragment.init()` callback (if Error.NONE) like so

```
val adapter = SuggestionsAdapter(context!!, R.layout.item_address, map.center)
binding.searchBox.setAdapter(adapter)
```

Then you could observe `isFetching` to reflect loading state

Answer (score 0):

The Adapter for your AutoCompleteTextView only filters elements that start with the input entered by the user. You need to modify the ArrayAdapter class in order for it to work.

```html
public class AutoSuggestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

private Context context;

private int resource;

private List<String> tempItems;

private List<String> suggestions;

 
public AutoSuggestAdapter(Context context, int resource, int item, List<String> items) {
    super(context, resource, item, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resource;
    tempItems = new ArrayList<>(items);
    suggestions = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return nameFilter;
    }

    Filter nameFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
            String str = (String) resultValue;
            return str;
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            if (constraint != null) {
                suggestions.clear();
                for (String names : tempItems) {
                    if (names.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        suggestions.add(names);
                    }
                }
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = suggestions;
                filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
                return filterResults;
            } else {
                return new FilterResults();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            List<String> filterList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                clear();
                for (String item : filterList) {
                    add(item);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Note that the important line is here:

```html
names.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())
```

This way it will search for a string that contains the string in the input. By default it's startsWith() intead of contains()

Comment: The problem is that request returns string address in format "region, city, street, house". I mean, it includes punctuations, but I need to ignore it. Should I modify source string every time for matching?

Comment: Yes what you can do is remove punctuation from the string before adding it to the adapter.

Comment: There is another way you can do this is to build another array with punctuation, then in the publishResults() in the for loop get the index of the item and then search for "item" with punctuation in the second array and modify the line: add(item) to add(string with punctuation), this way user searches without punctuation but the suggestions are punctuated